# Unable to sign in with google with compileSDK 34

Tags: java, android, google-oauth, google-signin

I can't able to login my app suddenly with google after the target sdk version updates. I am getting Could not sign-in to google, make sure to call onStart/onStop methods to initialize GoogleApiClient properly.